# Finding the $n$th term for the sequence $1, \frac{1}{2}, 3, \frac{1}{4}, 5, \frac{1}{6}, \dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, pattern-recognition

I have tried using a negative exponent.  I need one statement not two, the pattern is 
$$1, \; \frac{1}{2}, \; 3, \; \frac{1}{4}, \; 5, \; \frac{1}{6}, \dots$$

Comment: $n^{(-1)^{n+1}}$

Comment: how do i mark answered

Comment: You cannot unless some one replies an anwer and you have an option to tick mark it... approve it as an answer.

Comment: ok thx both of you

Comment: @DavidMitra No offence, would you mind if I post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Hawk I posted a hint. I suppose I should have done that to start... In the future, though, feel free to post.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: You can express it by $n^{a_n}$, where the $a_n$ give the appropriate power needed. For $n$ even, you want $a_n=1$ and for $n$ odd, you want $n=-1$ (recall $x^{-y}=1/x^y$).

So what formula  gives $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$?

Answer (score 0):

$$1, \frac{1}{2} , 3, \frac{1}{4} , 5, \frac{1}{6} \dots$$

The nth term would be: $n$ if $n$ is odd, and $\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, asking for a closed-form expression *without* using two different formulas for two cases.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple!
$(2n+1),\frac{n}{2}$ where $n$EZ.